# What is the best way to delete a joined association to a stored file in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to know the sql statement(s) to use to delete old data and the association to the old data without deleting the more important parent table, which should live forever.

I have the following tables:

```
Step
  Id bigint
  OccurredOn datetime
  ScreenshotId bigint

Screenshot
  Id bigint
  Data varbinary(max)
```

I want to delete all `Screenshot`s records associated with `Step`s where `OccurredOn` is more than 30 days old.  The `Step`s would still be persisted with a null `ScreenshotId`.

What is the best SQL Statement(s) to do this?

Comment: You may have your relationship / foreign key field on the wrong table .  From your explanation it seems that maybe you want to put a StepId field on the Screenshot table rather than having a ScreenShotId field on the step table.

Comment: It's a 1 to 1 relationship, so I suppose I could do it both ways.  Are you saying that I should do that to make deleting them easier?  Or are there other benefits to changing the relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE STEP
   SET screenshotid = NULL
 WHERE occurredon < DATEADD(dd, -30, GETDATE())

DELETE FROM SCREENSHOT
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM STEP s
                   WHERE s.screenshotid = id)
```

Comment: Mind that the DATEADD function will return a datetime which'll include the time portion (accurrate to ~3 ms?).

Comment: It seems so obvious now that I see the answer.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, you cannot use the OUTPUT clause chaining directly, but [this method (live runnable version)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6756/so3208939) ensures that you will only actually delete any screenshot rows you just orphaned (as opposed to any existing orphans):

```
-- SO3208939
CREATE TABLE #Screenshot (
    Id bigint IDENTITY(100000, 10) NOT NULL
    ,Data varbinary(max) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #Step (
    Id bigint IDENTITY NOT NULL
    ,OccurredOn datetime NOT NULL
    ,ScreenshotId bigint NULL REFERENCES #Screenshot(Id)
)

INSERT INTO #Screenshot DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #Step VALUES ('1/1/2010', @@IDENTITY)
INSERT INTO #Screenshot DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #Step VALUES ('2/1/2010', @@IDENTITY)
INSERT INTO #Screenshot DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #Step VALUES ('3/1/2010', @@IDENTITY)
INSERT INTO #Screenshot DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #Step VALUES ('4/1/2010', @@IDENTITY)
INSERT INTO #Screenshot DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #Step VALUES ('5/1/2010', @@IDENTITY)
INSERT INTO #Screenshot DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #Step VALUES ('6/1/2010', @@IDENTITY)
INSERT INTO #Screenshot DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #Step VALUES ('7/1/2010', @@IDENTITY)
INSERT INTO #Screenshot DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #Step VALUES ('8/1/2010', @@IDENTITY)

-- SELECT * FROM #Screenshot
-- SELECT * FROM #Step

DECLARE @Deleted AS TABLE (Id bigint NOT NULL)

UPDATE #Step
SET ScreenshotId = NULL
OUTPUT DELETED.ScreenshotId
INTO @Deleted
WHERE OccurredOn < DATEADD(dd, -30, GETDATE())

DELETE FROM #Screenshot
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @Deleted)

-- SELECT * FROM #Step
SELECT * FROM #Screenshot
```